# Page not rendering after postback occuring in dropdownlist selectedindex changed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rendering, pagertemplate

It is a strange problem. I am setting the pagesize of gridview in dropdownlist selectedindexchanged which is i gridview pager template. Here is my html source

```
<PagerTemplate>
                        <div class="grid-footer">
                            <div class="gridfooter_size">                           <asp:DropDownList ID="pageSize2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                    onselectedindexchanged="pageSize2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="10" Selected="True">10</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="25">25</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="50">50</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="100">100</asp:ListItem>                                  
                              </asp:DropDownList>

                            </div>
                            <div class="gridfooter_info">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSummary" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gridfooter_paginate">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFirstbnt" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CssClass="pagerclass-nxt"
                                    CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="First">First</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrevbnt" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CssClass="pagerclass-prev"
                                    CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="Prev">Previous</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Label ID="CurrentPage" CssClass="pagerclass-number" Visible="false" runat="server"
                                    Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNextbnt" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CssClass="pagerclass-next"
                                    CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="Next">Next</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLastbnt" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CssClass="pagerclass-last"
                                    CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="Last">Last</asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </PagerTemplate>
```

Here is my code behind

```
Protected Sub pageSize2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim gvr2 As GridViewRow = GridView2.BottomPagerRow
    Dim ddPageSize2 As DropDownList = DirectCast(gvr2.Cells(0).FindControl("pageSize2"), DropDownList)
    GridView2.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddPageSize2.SelectedValue)
    Call GetDataTables2()
End Sub
```

When post back is occured the `pageSize2_SelectedIndexChanged` event is firing for all the selectd values of dropdownlist, but the page is not rendering. It is jumping from the pageSize2_SelectedIndexChanged event `Call GetDataTables2()` method. **If the dropdownlist selectd value is 10, then the page is rendering**, it strange. What might be the problem, Please suggest solution

Comment: Put your ASPX code inside an update panel and check..

Comment: It is already in update panel itself.

Comment: Try to save your selected value in a Session or a Viewstate on pageSize2_SelectedIndexChanged event and in Page_Load event set DropDownList value to saved value.

Comment: Thank you @tarzanbappa. Problem is solved. The problem is, I have used templated field in gridview, in those I draged lables. All the lables took ID as label1 as default. I didn't check that. Because of same IDs it is not rendering the page and which is in update pane, so didn't show any error message. :)

Comment: yeah. ;) nice to hear dat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, I am using two gridviews in the same update panel. And those two gridviews **having the controsl with same IDs under the templates of two gridviews**. This might be a bug in visual studio. It did not tell me any compile time exception and not even in runtime until I remove the updatepanel. I ahve changed the control IDs. Now it is working fine.